# Can't centralize side-by-side pair of radioGroups in Android Studio

Tags: android, layout, android-studio

I cannot get the layout below such that the two side-by-side radioGroups centralize. At the moment, they are a little to the right. As soon as I try to adjust anything (either by clicking and dragging or by modifying the xml, all hell breaks loose and either the entire display vanishes or it gets corrupted.

I want to say, basically:

1. Center the top textfield and the Pass button.
2. Center the boundary between the two radioGroups.
3. Align the left hand side of the Double button to the left hand side of the left hand radio group.
4. Align the right hand side of the Redouble button to the right hand side of the right hand radioGRoup.
5. Align the "Small text" text field in the center, not to the left.
6. Align the Next button in the center.

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Code and image follow.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="com.example.owner.bidmate.WhatBid"
            android:background="#29ff3a">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="very long text so it widens the field"
    android:id="@+id/bidtitle"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Pass"
    android:id="@+id/passButton"
    android:checked="false"
    android:textOff="Pass"
    android:textOn="Pass"
    android:background="#080dff"
    android:textColor="#fafff8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bidtitle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:background="#befffc"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/passButton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/radioGroup2"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/radioGroup2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="One"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:checked="false"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Two"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:checked="false"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Three"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:checked="false"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Four"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:checked="false"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Five"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
        android:checked="false"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Six"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton6"
        android:checked="false"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Seven"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton7"
        android:checked="false"/>

</RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
    android:background="#c7fffd"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/redoubleButton"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/redoubleButton"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Club"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton8"
        android:checked="false"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Diamond"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton9"
        android:checked="false"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Heart"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton10"
        android:checked="false"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Spade"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton11"
        android:checked="false"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No Trump"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton12"
        android:checked="false"/>

</RadioGroup>

<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Double"
    android:id="@+id/doubleButton"
    android:checked="false"
    android:textOff="Double"
    android:textOn="Double"
    android:background="#ff151a"
    android:textColor="#fefffd"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioGroup"/>

<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Redouble"
    android:id="@+id/redoubleButton"
    android:checked="false"
    android:textOff="Redouble"
    android:textOn="Redouble"
    android:background="#ff1521"
    android:textColor="#fbfffb"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/wbnextbutton"

    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup2"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/doubleButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    android:id="@+id/wbnextbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/passButton"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/passButton"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.owner.bidmate.WhatBid"
    android:background="#29ff3a">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="very long text so it widens the field"
        android:id="@+id/bidtitle"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pass"
        android:id="@+id/passButton"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textOff="Pass"
        android:textOn="Pass"
        android:background="#080dff"
        android:textColor="#fafff8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bidtitle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:background="#befffc"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passButton"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/temp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="One"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:checked="false"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Two"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:checked="false"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Three"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:checked="false"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Four"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
            android:checked="false"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Five"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
            android:checked="false"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Six"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton6"
            android:checked="false"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Seven"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton7"
            android:checked="false"/>

    </RadioGroup>
    <View android:layout_below="@+id/passButton" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="1dp" android:id="@+id/temp"></View>
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:background="#c7fffd"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/temp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Club"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton8"
            android:checked="false"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Diamond"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton9"
            android:checked="false"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Heart"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton10"
            android:checked="false"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Spade"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton11"
            android:checked="false"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No Trump"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton12"
            android:checked="false"/>

    </RadioGroup>

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Double"
        android:id="@+id/doubleButton"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textOff="Double"
        android:textOn="Double"
        android:background="#ff151a"
        android:textColor="#fefffd"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioGroup"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Redouble"
        android:id="@+id/redoubleButton"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textOff="Redouble"
        android:textOn="Redouble"
        android:background="#ff1521"
        android:textColor="#fbfffb"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/wbnextbutton"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/doubleButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:id="@+id/wbnextbutton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Tiny Sunlight. I've just seen your answer and will study the edits you have made and try it tomorrow because in my part of the world, it's now nearly midnight. Will comment again once tried.

Comment: Tiny, you are a star! Your code worked first time. (I'm sure you knew it would!) May I ask you please, this ruse of placing what I would call "a pin in the board", is this a standard and recognized technique? And secondly, is calling it "temp" also the conventional name for such a thing?
Thank you again, very much.

Comment: It 's just experience.temp is just short for temporary,because id for it is not  so important.